# ImageMagick - alpha channel extract, different results (darker) on 6.7 vs 6.9

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, opacity, alpha, imagemagick-convert

I'm working in a cross-platform environment where the results of the same, simple alpha channel extraction operation are different between ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 and ImageMagick 6.9.3-7.

The command to extract the alpha channel is:

```
convert image.png -alpha extract alpha.png
```

Or equivalently: `convert image.png -channel A -separate alpha.png`

Here is the original, the 6.7 output, and the 6.9 output:

[image]

Testing the original in Gimp, in the middle of the top dark bar, I can see that the original alpha value was 80% or 204:

[image]

The 6.9 output has grayscale value of 204, while the 6.7 output has a grayscale value of 154.

**Now the question:** I believe the 6.9 version is correct, but we like the visual result provided by the 6.7 version. Can we understand how the 6.7 version was working (maybe some different formula / luminence / color space?) and get the same result from the 6.9 version? Maybe apply some curve to the 6.9 output? Or some switch to make it use a different formula / color space? (Do color spaces even apply to PNGs?)

Comment: I would believe the later version as from memory there were a few changes around version 6.7 The only way you can confirm it is an operating system problem is to run the same two version on the two machines.

Comment: I don't have your environment to test, but you could try `convert input.png -alpha extract result.png`.

Comment: @Bonzo - yes, it's probably version related vs OS related, but my question is the same regardless. How to get the other output. I'll try to download an updated ImageMagick for Linux to determine if it's version or OS that matters. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkSetchell - yes, I tested the `-alpha extract` command also, and the results were unchanged -- it produces different results on the different OS / version. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I know the colourspace handling changed around the 6.7 version, but I am having difficulty thinking how that could affect the alpha channel - since that only relates to the degree of visibility not to any colour AFAIK. Still, you could add in `-set colorspace RGB` or `-set colorspace sRGB` after loading the input image and *"suck it and see"* - technical term ;-)

Comment: Indeed, colorspace args make no difference, trying both RGB and sRGB on both OS / versions. On the compiling front -- I downloaded 6.9.3.7 for Linux, compiled it, and indeed, it's version that matters. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2):

Post processing the 6.9 output with this simple gamma adjustment gives a very close approximation of the 6.7 output:

```
convert /tmp/alpha_channel_6.9.png -gamma 0.4472 /tmp/alpha_gamma_0.4472.png
```

Here's a [gist of our solution](https://gist.github.com/jcward/cd16b781a2752332bd52e123fb9669d4) in a shell script to detect 6.7 and apply the gamma adjustment selectively.

---

Note: Compared to the -fx answer, the gamma adjustment runs faster is more accurate, judging by less statistical error (MAE of 190 vs 408) found with:

```
compare -verbose -metric MAE /tmp/alpha_channel_6.7.png /tmp/alpha_curved.png null: 2>&1
compare -verbose -metric MAE /tmp/alpha_channel_6.7.png /tmp/alpha_gamma_0.4472.png null: 2>&1
```

But I'm going to leave the -fx answer in place, because I like the process of finding curves it describes.

---

Incidentally, this command lightens 6.7 output to look like 6.9 output:

```
convert /tmp/alpha_channel_6.7.png -gamma 2.22 /tmp/alpha_gamma_to_look_like_6.9.png
```

But with such a big gamma boost, the results are pretty ugly with color banding in the dark areas:

[image]

Comment: Well done and thanks for sharing your findings back with everyone.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks! It took half the day, but it's nice to have a solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Deprecated:** The -gamma answer is faster and provides better results, but I'll leave the below info, as it could be useful for other problems needing a "curves" solution.

---

Ok, I was able to post-process my 6.9 alpha channel output with a curves function so that it *very closely* matches the 6.7 alpha channel output.

However, if someone has a more concise switch, let me know!

### Long story short, here's the post processing step:

It uses convert's -fx filter to apply curves to make 6.9 alpha channel output look like 6.7:

```
convert /tmp/alpha_channel_6.9.png -fx "-0.456633863737214*u^4 + 1.33965176221586*u^3 + -0.0837635742856742*u^2 + 0.199687083827961*u +0.00105015974839925" /tmp/alpha_curved_to_look_like_6.7.png
```

One could figure out the inverse function, to make 6.7 look like 6.9, given enough motivation.

### Note to my future self, here's waaay too many details about how to derive this function:

Ok, so there's a page on ImageMagick's website about [achieving a "curves" effect](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#curves). The fun part is, it uses gnuplot to fit a polynomial to the curves function that'd you'd normally see in Gimp or Photoshop.

So I had the idea that I could create a [test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd9zj.png) (note, it's white with alpha, so not easy to see), run it through [6.7 alpha extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1iWg.png) and [6.9 alpha extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSNyH.png), and visually compare them (on separate layers) in Gimp:

[image]

Then poke around in the curves tool on the 6.9 layer to make it look exactly like the 6.7 image:

[image]

Ok, so I found the curve I want. Now luckily, in Gimp, if you hover over the curve plot, it tells you the coordinates of the cursor, so I can find the coordinates of my curve to fit with gnuplot (as described in the link above. Note, I had to convert from 0-255 to 0.0-1.0.)

Cut super gory details, see this [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugmb5.png) of the general idea.

Note that I updated the ImageMagick code to fit a 4th degree polynomial, as it gave a better fit than their 3rd degree for me:

```
( echo 'f(x) = a*x**4 + b*x**3 + c*x**2 + d*x + e';     echo 'fit f(x) "fx_control.txt" via a, b, c, d, e';     echo 'print a,"*x^4 + ",b,"*x^3 + ",c,"*x^2 + ",d,"*x +",e';   ) | gnuplot 2>&1 | tail -1 > fx_funct.txt
```

This output:

-0.456633863737214*x^4 + 1.33965176221586*x^3 + -0.0837635742856742*x^2 + 0.199687083827961*x +0.00105015974839925

Ok, I used the above to generate a function of X, and plotted it using desmos.com, then screencapped that plot (in red) to overlay and compare it to the gimp curves. Looks pretty close to me:

[image]

So finally, switch the x's to u's, and plug it into ImageMagick, and voila, my 6.9 output looks like my 6.7 output once again:

```
convert /tmp/alpha_channel_6.9.png -fx "-0.456633863737214*u^4 + 1.33965176221586*u^3 + -0.0837635742856742*u^2 + 0.199687083827961*u +0.00105015974839925" /tmp/alpha_curved_to_look_like_6.7.png
```